# Regex in Python: Open a file that contains certain character or pattern

Tags: python, regex, file

Is it possible in python to open a file that contain certain characters or patterns that other files in that directory for example i have 5 files in a directory:

```
file1.py file2.py file2_0.out file_1.out file1.out file2.out
```

I would like to only open the files that end with "_0.out" and "_1.out" I am not familiar with regex in python or if it can be used. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://www.google.de/search?q=python+regex

Comment: Also see [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html).

Comment: No I didn't and will do so, thank you

Answer (score 4):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems. -- Jamie Zawinski

That being said, `regex` might be overkill for this. The `str` class has a `endswith` method that you can use in a list comprehension to handle this.

```
>>> l = ['file1.py', 'file2.py', 'file2_0.out', 'file_1.out', 'file1.out', 'file2.out',]
>>> [i for i in l if i.endswith(('_0.out','_1.out'))]
['file2_0.out', 'file_1.out']
```

Comment: haha, thanks, your answer's exactly what I was about to submit, and I was searching for that amazing quote about regex when I saw you posted it.

Comment: @cyber very nice quote.